# Spring boot - slow method execution

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a huge problem with method execution (I guess). I'm using Spring boot 2.0 (tested with 1.5.x as well) + Thymeleaf 3.

**The case:**

When the application is running for more about 48 h (for e.g), submitting the simple POST form with 2 fields takes appr. 15 seconds. The method doesn't call anything related to DB.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTile(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("tile") Tile tile, BindingResult results) {

    if(results.hasErrors()){
        return "tile/add";
    }
    tileRepository.save(tile);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

After many tests that I've made, no memory, JDBC, connection leeks and etc. were found.

From GC point of view, there isn't any strange too.

I used jProfiler and from method stack execution, the delay comes from the method itself.

When I switched the VPS to another hosting provider and changed sessions to redis, the performance was dramatically improved maybe with 30%-40%, but still doesn't work properly.

I've tested the app with jMeter for concurrency issues but everything is perfect and the response is very good.

This issues comes out only if the application is running more thatn 24h/48h and there is no active users.

The version of JVM is Java 8 OpenJDK (build 1.8.0_151-b12) without any custom settings.

Comment: It's very difficult to come with a proper answer on questions like these. Are you sure you're not having any stale connections to the database? If your entire database connection pool became stale, it can take a while before all connections are invalidated and a new one is being generated.

Comment: You are right. I just want suggestions. The problem is that the method doesn't call a DB connection :) Even if the form is empty ( validation takes place and the view is returned before to finish the whole method.

Comment: In that case, what does `tileRepository.save()` do then?

Comment: The problem exists when I submit an empty form, where tileRepository.save() is not called.

Comment: Well you think it doesn't use a DB connection. If you are using JPA and run with the defaults you have an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` added to your chain by default. What happens is that upon a request the `EntityManager` is bound to the current thread (and with that a connection). Now after 24 to 48 hours of being inactive you have probably no valid DB connections anymore. Those will be closed one by one until a fresh one is retrieved from the database. I suggest configure your datasource to test connections when idle that way you always have active connections.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I learned something new :) Before the update to spring-boot 2, I've used 1.5.3 with Tomcat connection pool. Now I'm using Hikari connection pool. Some settings that I've used.
# Maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this 
#spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
#spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1